# Can't get search logic to work in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

So I'm trying to get a form with multiple value to work. I have like a min price range, max, area, city, and a search query for words. I've created separate "blocks" to check for each then get results, and I plan or merging the arrays together. Is this a good way to proceed? Here's what I got for example.

```
//Get post response
if(isset($_POST['query']) && isset($_POST['price1']) && isset($_POST['price2']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['area'])){
    $query = $_POST['query'];
    $price1a = $_POST['price1'];
    $price2a = $_POST['price2'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $area = $_POST['area'];
}

//Make sure price is INT
$price1 = (int)$price1a;
$price2 = (int)$price2a;

echo $price1;

//Check to see which fields are empty
if(empty($query) && empty($price1) && empty($price2) && empty($city) && empty($area)){
    //User didn't bother entering anything, just return everything
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_posts");
    $stmt->execute();

    //Return as JSON string for parsing via front
    $json = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    echo $json;
}

//Price range for two INT
if(!empty($price1) || !empty($price2)){
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE price BETWEEN :price1 AND :price2");
    $stmt->bindValue(':price1', $price1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':price2', $price2);
    $stmt->execute();

    $json = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    echo $json;
}

//Price range for one INT, no max
if(!empty($price1) && empty($price2)){
    //Only price two is empty, therefore no max, so set a large number
    $max = 100000000;
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE price BETWEEN :price1 aND :price2");
    $stmt->bindValue(':price1', $price1);
    $stmt->bindValue(':price2', $max);
    $stmt->execute();

    $json = json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
    echo $json;
}
```

This is only a small part, but the two lower if statements show the min and max price.  I was planning on getting those two results then merging the JSON. Will this work? Any better way of a "multi input search"?

Comment: What do you mean merging those two results? Only one of the two conditions will be fulfilled, the conditions are mutually exclusive. And by the way, the first condition should be `!empty($price1) && !empty($price2)` if I means that "if both price1 and price2 are not empty" i.e. you have both the upper and lower ranges,

Comment: I was planning on going through the script to see what results get returned then I'd take the JSON and merge it. Since I get an array returned from the database. @dg131